# Array query in Scala and ReactiveMongo?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I have a MongoDB collection whose documents look like this:

```
{
    "name" : "fabio",
    "items" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "word" : "xxxx"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "word" : "yyyy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, given one name and one id, I want to retrieve "name" and the corresponding "word".
I query it like this and it seems to work:

```
val query = BSONDocument("name" -> name, "items.id" -> id)
```

But then, how do I access the value of "word"? I can get the name using this reader:
The reader for this object is like this:

```
implicit object UserReader extends BSONDocumentReader[User] {
    def read(doc: BSONDocument): User = {
      val name = doc.getAs[String]("name").get

      // how do I retrive the value of "word"?

      User(id, word)
    }
  }
```

But I am very confused about "word".

Additionally, because I am only interested in two fields, how should I filter the query? The following doesn't seem to work.

```
val filter = BSONDocument("name" -> 1, "items.$.word" -> 1)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When You have an `id` in elements in your array You can try to store them as an object where id is the key. Like this: `{"items": {"1" : {"word":"xxxx"}}}`